# CSS - Add blank line between div elements

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

My sample UI looks like below:

[image]

Here I need to add a blank lines after the textboxes. That means there will be a blank line after first textbox and another blank line after the second textbox. Below is how my `cshtml` file looks like:

```
<style>
    .divTable {
        display: table;
        border: none;
    }

    .divRow {
        display: table-row;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .divTable input, .divTable select {
        padding: 2px;
        border: solid 1px #BCC3C8;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .divTable button {
        margin-top: -5px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>

<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divRow">
        <div class="divCell1">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)</div>
        <div class="divCell2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">
        <div class="divCell1">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)</div>
        <div class="divCell2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

But I am not getting desired output. The output is the same as the above screenshot. How to do this ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put padding on `divRow`?

Comment: Your reputation is fake I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The css syntax for having styles when one element follows another is:

```
element1 + element2{
    //styles
}
```

so you can do this:

```
.class_of_element1 + .class_of_element2{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

or

```
#id_of_element1 + #id_of_element2{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

[**SAMPLE JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtj9E/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a margin below the `divCell2`:

```
.divRow .divCell2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below. You need to add a `margin-bottom` to add spacing as per your requirements.

**For Instance,**

```
.divTable input, .divTable select{margin-bottom:30px;}
```

***PS:** 30px is illustrative. You can increase/decrease as per your convenience.*